# FabricJS setControlVisible for specific object and not for all objects of that type?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fabricjs

**Context**

I'm using Fabric.js, and I have multiple objects of the same type.

**Problem**

When I use `obj.setControlVisible('tl', true)` it enables the top left controls for all objects of that type, instead of that object specifically.

**Expected or what I want to accomplish**

I want to turn visible the top left control only for that specific object.

**Versions**

- Fabric 3.2.0
- React 17.0.2
- typescript 4.8.4